# pyqgis 3 QgsVectorLayer.startEditing() doesn't trigger vertex display

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, vertices, pyqgis-3, qgsvectorlayer

In pyqgis 2 standalone application, the following code will trigger the display of vertex as red cross mark, but in pyqgis 3.0.3 standalone application, it doesn't:

```
layer.startEditing()
mapCanvas.refresh()
```

why is that? Do we have to somehow manually trigger the vertex markers to be displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine, the likely issue is that there is a default setting which only shows vertices when editing **selected features**. You can check this by going to:

```
Settings > Options > Digitizing > Vertex markers
```

[image: Digitizing settings]

Uncheck this and run your code again, the vertices should now show up for all features.

Comment: this looks promising, just that this is a standalone pyqgis 3 application, how to unset this setting through a function call?

Comment: @ForComment - Maybe try something like: `from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings`; `QSettings().setValue("/Qgis/digitizing/marker_only_for_selected", False)`. This works from the console but can't confirm for a standalone application.

Comment: Yes, the QSetting code worked. Just need to do this at the top of the module, then it displays all vertices' markers

Comment: @ForComment - Nice one! Glad it helped :)